# Vicidial in Autodial does not connect correctly dongle phone call to agent conference

Tags: asterisk

I want to make work Vicidial with [chan_dongle](http://wiki.e1550.mobi) Asterisk module to use Huawei USB modems as GSM gateways (trunks/carriers) for asterisk.

In manual mode everything works.

Problem appears only if [Vicidial](http://vicidial.org) Campaign is set to AUTODIAL mode and calls are made in backround and after answering by customer should be connected to live SIP conference call to which agent is connected.

Problem is that Local channel for that call is made and just after answering is hung up and not connected to conference. This is for every call. beside of this agent is connected to customer and can talk to him, but after 33 seconds he looses call control and only customer can hung call.

in manual mode everything is working ok and conference contain 2 channels in it local (phone call made by dongle) and sip (connection from zoiper to asterisk).

my dongle dialplan:

```
exten => _915.,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
exten => _915.,n,Dial(Dongle/g1/${EXTEN:3},20,oTtr)
exten => _915.,n,Hangup
```

my dongle.conf:

```
[defaults]
; now you can set here any not required device settings as template
;   sure you can overwrite in any [device] section this default values

context=trunkinbound                    ; context for incoming calls
group=0                         ; calling group
rxgain=0                        ; increase the incoming volume; may be negative
txgain=0                        ; increase the outgoint volume; may be negative
autodeletesms=yes               ; auto delete incoming sms
resetdongle=yes                 ; reset dongle during initialization with ATZ command
u2diag=0                        ; set ^U2DIAG parameter on device (0 = disable everything except modem function) ; -1 not use ^U2DIAG command
usecallingpres=yes              ; use the caller ID presentation or not
callingpres=allowed_passed_screen ; set caller ID presentation          by default use default network settings
disablesms=no                   ; disable of SMS reading from device when received
                                ;  chan_dongle has currently a bug with SMS reception. When a SMS gets in during a
                                ;  call chan_dongle might crash. Enable this option to disable sms reception.
                                ;  default = no

language=en                     ; set channel default language
smsaspdu=yes                    ; if 'yes' send SMS in PDU mode, feature implementation incomplete and we strongly recommend say 'yes'
mindtmfgap=45                   ; minimal interval from end of previews DTMF from begining of next in ms
mindtmfduration=80              ; minimal DTMF tone duration in ms
mindtmfinterval=200             ; minimal interval between ends of DTMF of same digits in ms

callwaiting=auto                ; if 'yes' allow incoming calls waiting; by default use network settings
                                ; if 'no' waiting calls just ignored
disable=no                      ; OBSOLETED by initstate: if 'yes' no load this device and just ignore this section

initstate=start                 ; specified initial state of device, must be one of 'stop' 'start' 'remote'
                                ;   'remove' same as 'disable=yes'

;exten=+1234567890              ; exten for start incoming calls, only in case of Subscriber Number not available!, also set to CALLERID(ndid)

dtmf=relax                      ; control of incoming DTMF detection, possible values:
                                ;   off    - off DTMF tones detection, voice data passed to asterisk unaltered
                                ;              use this value for gateways or if not use DTMF for AVR or inside dialplan
                                ;   inband - do DTMF tones detection
                                ;   relax  - like inband but with relaxdtmf option
                                ;  default is 'relax' by compatibility reason

[dongle0]
group=1
audio=/dev/ttyUSB1              
data=/dev/ttyUSB2
```

full log

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BytawwAUUbX2ZlJNaVk2ZXpuMjg/edit?usp=sharing

please help

if more information will be helpful please write, I will try to provide them.